# How to create a tablayout similar view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-view, android-tablayout

I am trying to create a simple layout that would look similar to a `TabLayout` but I don't need to have actual tabs. It would just be acting like a plain button.
I am not sure if this should be done via background drawable (to handle change of state and color of line) or via just views.
Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make separate buttons / relative / image layouts as buttons. And change fragments in frameLayout. I can't say it is good practice but at the same time I don't know your situation. But Im sure it will work and you can easy custom each part of the process and view.

Comment: What do you mean by `change fragments in frameLayout`?

Comment: @Jim TabLayout is ready to use structure which provided to developers. Nobody prohibit you to do the same things your own way with custom views. So if functionality is not enough you can make your own.  First variant make it with help of separate part / second override and extend .

Comment: It is not that the functionality is not enough. I thought that this component is meant to be used in order to change "tabs" in the screen. I just want to have a component that looks like the tab layout i.e. has the line dividor in the bottom. Can I extend the `TabLayout` for that purpose or would it be a misuse?

Answer (score 0):

Use a customized `TabLayout`

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"        // select your height
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/buttons_selector"  // this to customize tabs
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/your_tab_text_color"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextAppearance"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"    // hide the indicator line
        app:tabGravity="fill"           // or center
        app:tabMode="fixed"            // or scrollable
    >
```

drawable buttons_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- drawable for selected tab -->
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_selected"
        android:state_selected="true"/>

    <!-- drawable for unselected tab -->
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_not_selected"
        android:state_selected="false"/>
</selector>
```

drawable button_not_selected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <!-- unselected tab background -->
    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
```

drawable button_selected

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners  android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" />

    <!-- color of the selected tab -->
    <solid
        android:color="@color/your_color"/>
</shape>
```

You can play with colours, radius, etc.

Comment: Is this supposed to have ` android.support.design.widget.TabItem` as children?

Comment: Yes. So, instead of creating a new component that works as a `TabLayout`, use a `TabLayout` (with all its functionalities) with `TabItems` that works as `Buttons`.